# How do you retrieve the response body and use it as the request body for a subsequent request?

Tags: api, testing, automation, postman

Get request is the initial request. I manually copy the response body result and paste it into the other post request body. How can this process be automated?

After I run my collection, I am expecting to see the response body from the get request in the request body of the Post request

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Tests' tab in postman to extract the response body first and then use it in the next call.
You can use the following piece of code for extracting and storing the response body in a variable 'responseData'

```
let response = pm.response.json(),

responseData = JSON.stringify(response);
pm.collectionVariables.set("responseData", responseData);
```

Now your response body is stored in the variable 'responseData'

You can pass this as a request body just by mentioning this in your request payload -

```
{{responseData}}
```